# How to create a route on google maps with a location information?

Tags: android, google-maps

I have an application. I have a location information to google maps. I want to create a path from where I am using google maps.

```
 String url = "yandexmaps://maps.yandex.ru/?pt=" + routePlan.getLocationLat() + "" + routePlan.getLocationLong() + "&z=12&l=map";
        Intent intentYandex = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        intentYandex.setPackage("ru.yandex.yandexmaps");

        String uriGoogle = "geo:" +routePlan.getLocationLat()+"," + routePlan.getLocationLong();
        Intent intentGoogle = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(uriGoogle));
        intentGoogle.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");

        String title = "Select";
        Intent chooserIntent = Intent.createChooser(intentGoogle, title);
        Intent[] arr = new Intent[1];
        arr[0] = intentYandex;
        chooserIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_INITIAL_INTENTS, arr);
        startActivity(chooserIntent);
```

Comment: Post your code, you have tried

Comment: @RahulChaudhary I shared my code. I'm just sending location information to google maps.

Answer (score 0):

Google has services for it. You can use Google Maps sdk and Google's Directions Api

Just send an http request to google's directions api

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/outputFormat?parameters
```

It will return a json response like this:

```
   {
   "geocoded_waypoints" : [
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "place_id" : "ChIJRVY_etDX3IARGYLVpoq7f68",
         "types" : [
            "bus_station",
            "transit_station",
            "point_of_interest",
            "establishment"
         ]
      },
      {
         "geocoder_status" : "OK",
         "partial_match" : true,
         "place_id" : "ChIJp2Mn4E2-woARQS2FILlxUzk",
         "types" : [ "route" ]
      }
   ],
   "routes" : [
      {
         "bounds" : {
            "northeast" : {
               "lat" : 34.1330949,
               "lng" : -117.9143879
            },
            "southwest" : {
               "lat" : 33.8068768,
               "lng" : -118.3527671
            }
         },
         "copyrights" : "Map data ©2016 Google",
         "legs" : [
            {
               "distance" : {
                  "text" : "35.9 mi",
                  "value" : 57824
               },
               "duration" : {
                  "text" : "51 mins",
                  "value" : 3062
               },
               "end_address" : "Universal Studios Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90068, USA",
               "end_location" : {
                  "lat" : 34.1330949,
                  "lng" : -118.3524442
               },
               "start_address" : "Disneyland (Harbor Blvd.), S Harbor Blvd, Anaheim, CA 92802, USA",
               "start_location" : {
                  "lat" : 33.8098177,
                  "lng" : -117.9154353
               },

  ... Additional results truncated in this example[] ...


         "overview_polyline" : {
            "points" : "knjmEnjunUbKCfEA?_@]@kMBeE@qIIoF@wH@eFFk@WOUI_@?u@j@k@`@EXLTZHh@Y`AgApAaCrCUd@cDpDuAtAoApA{YlZiBdBaIhGkFrDeCtBuFxFmIdJmOjPaChDeBlDiAdD}ApGcDxU}@hEmAxD}[tt@yNb\\yBdEqFnJqB~DeFxMgK~VsMr[uKzVoCxEsEtG}BzCkHhKWh@]t@{AxEcClLkCjLi@`CwBfHaEzJuBdEyEhIaBnCiF|K_Oz\\
            {MdZwAbDaKbUiB|CgCnDkDbEiE|FqBlDsLdXqQra@kX|m@aF|KcHtLm@pAaE~JcTxh@w\\`v@gQv`@}F`MqK`PeGzIyGfJiG~GeLhLgIpIcE~FsDrHcFfLqDzH{CxEwAbBgC|B}F|DiQzKsbBdeA{k@~\\oc@bWoKjGaEzCoEzEwDxFsUh^wJfOySx[uBnCgCbCoFlDmDvAiCr@eRzDuNxC_EvAiFpCaC|AqGpEwHzFoQnQoTrTqBlCyDnGmCfEmDpDyGzGsIzHuZzYwBpBsC`CqBlAsBbAqCxAoBrAqDdDcNfMgHbHiPtReBtCkD|GqAhBwBzBsG~FoAhAaCbDeBvD_BlEyM``@uBvKiA~DmAlCkA|B}@lBcChHoJnXcB`GoAnIS~CIjFDd]A|QMlD{@jH[vAk@`CoGxRgPzf@aBbHoB~HeMx^eDtJ}BnG{DhJU`@mBzCoCjDaAx@mAnAgCnBmAp@uAj@{Cr@wBPkB@kBSsEW{GV}BEeCWyAWwHs@qH?
            cIHkDXuDn@mCt@mE`BsH|CyAp@}AdAaAtAy@lBg@pCa@jE]fEcBhRq@pJKlCk@hLFrB@lD_@xCeA`DoBxDaHvM_FzImDzFeCpDeC|CkExDiJrHcBtAkDpDwObVuCpFeCdHoIl\\uBjIuClJsEvMyDbMqAhEoDlJ{C|J}FlZuBfLyDlXwB~QkArG_AnDiAxC{G|OgEdLaE`LkBbEwG~KgHnLoEjGgDxCaC`BuJdFkFtCgCnBuClD_HdMqEzHcBpB_C|BuEzCmPlIuE|B_EtDeBhCgAdCw@rCi@|DSfECrCAdCS~Di@jDYhA_AlC{AxCcL`U{GvM_DjFkBzBsB`BqDhBaEfAsTvEmEr@iCr@qDrAiFnCcEzCaE~D_@JmFdGQDwBvCeErEoD|BcFjC}DbEuD~D`@Zr@h@?d@Wr@}@vAgCbEaHfMqA`Cy@dAg@bAO`@gCi@w@W"
         },
         "summary" : "I-5 N and US-101 N",
         "warnings" : [],
         "waypoint_order" : []
      }
   ],
   "status" : "OK"
}
```

### helpful links

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/intro
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/start